# No output files from Torque scheduler

Tags: torque

I am somewhat of a clustering neophyte and recently installed torque and the maui scheduler on a Debian cluster. To test the setup, I ran a simple pbs script `test_torque.sh` (see the script below).

Running `qsub test_torque.sh` seems to run fine, with the job appearing in `qstat` and changing status from `Q` to `R` to `C`.

The problem is that **no** output files are produced. I have done a thorough `find` and I don't see any job output files nor the diagnostic files specified in the pbs script.

I have checked the `server`, `mom`, and `maui` logs and don't see anything unusual (at least to my untrained eye).

I am able to ping all of the nodes from the server (and the server from all of the nodes)

Any clues as to what might be going on or additional diagnostics I can run?

Thank you for your help.

---

```
$ cat test_torque.sh

#!/bin/bash
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -e /home/gyro/temp/error.txt
#PBS -o /home/gyro/temp/output.txt

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
hostname
date
exit 0
```

---

```
$qsub --version
Version: master
Commit: cd7cd01bbe8915654c269435ec6d249aaa7f4965
```

---

```
$ uname -a
Linux cluster 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u3 (2017-08-15) 
x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can you connect with ssh from any node to the head node? Torque is by default using scp to copy log files from a spool directory on the node to the output directory on the head node. Also check if the output files are somewhere in a spool directory on the worker node.

Comment: Thanks for the clue! The files were indeed in the `undelivered` directory in the `spool` directory on one of the nodes. A curious thing is the error I am finding in one of the logs: `/var/log/messages:Sep 29 10:42:52 xxx pbs_mom: LOG_ERROR::Operation not permitted (1) in sys_copy, command '/usr/bin/scp -rpB /var/spool/torque/spool//450.xxx.xxxxx.OU xxx@xxxx:/home/xxxx/temp/test_torque2.sh.o450' failed with status=1, giving up after 4 attempts`. Note the double slash in the origin file name. I wonder if this is the cause of the issue.

Comment: One further comment: I can ssh from the compute nodes to the head node and vice versa.

Comment: Try to execute the command `/usr/bin/scp -rpB /var/spool/torque/spool//450.xxx.xxxxx.OU xxx@xxxx:/home/xxxx/temp/test_torque2.sh.o450` as user `xxx`. It is not necessary a permission error. I would guess that root user can ssh from compute nodes to head node without typing the password, but user `xxx` cannot. Though there might be other reasons

Comment: In general, the `scp` command seems to work fine as the xxx user. I think that the issue may be the part of the path with the double slash `//`. I don't know why that was generated as part of the `scp` command.

Comment: Are you saying that when you manually execute the command with double slash `/usr/bin/scp -rpB /var/spool/torque/spool//450.xxx.xxxxx.OU xxx@xxxx:/home/xxxx/temp/test_torque2.sh.o450`  it fails, but when you replace `//` with `/` it works normally?

Comment: No. The double slash does not work. When I execute a similar command,  with a proper path (e.g., `/usr/bin/scp -rpB /var/spool/torque/spool/undelivered/450.xxx.xxxxx.OU xxx@xxxx:/home/xxxx/temp/test_torque2.sh.o450`), it works.